# A 10 pixel wide bar shifted from right side to left side of screen in fullscreen video

Tags: multiple-monitors, 14.10, vlc, fglrx

In Ubuntu 14.10, in vlc and minecraft when they are displaying in either full screen or when maximized, a 10 pixel wide bar of the video is being shifted from the right side of my screen to the left side.  Notably, this doesn't happen when the window isn't maximized, but the video is the same width as when it is maximized.  I hope I've described the problem properly, as I can't post images with my current reputation.